# What can bash do: syntax highlighting, git info prompt and autocomplete based on the middle of a word?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, syntax-highlighting

I'm using [prezto framework for zsh](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) and started wondering if I really need `zsh`.

Main features I really enjoy are:

- syntax highlighting for commands,
- fancy prompt when in a `git` repository and
- the possibility of tabbing part of a word and it autocompletes (example: I have a list of images with the same suffix, *IMG_2567*, I do '`67 + tab`' it auto completes to *IMG_2567* - it's really handy).

Is it achievable only using *bash*?

Comment: fancy prompt: yes, with `PROMPT_COMMAND`. I don't know about the other two, I think not... But why would you not use zsh?

Comment: @Gilles all machines I use have bash, not all have zsh. I know zsh is not that hard to install, but one of the machines I can't install nothing and I was planning to use stuff that is already available (default) in Linux installations. Yes, I know about `PROMPT_COMMAND` but the other two features would be really nice.

Answer (score 3):

So far as I've seen:

1. Syntax highlighting for commands: not so much in `bash`.
2. `git`-aware prompt: yes if [liquidprompt](https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt) is installed.  (`liquidprompt` can also be installed over `zsh`.)
3. Autocompletion: nothing built in that does inclusive autocompletion
   by *suffix*, *infix*, and *prefix*.  `bash-completion` only provides
   *prefix*-based autocompletion.

   On *github* there's an *11K*
   [`fuzzy_bash_completion`](https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion)
   script that does do *suffix* and *infix* completion.